# Change Link Colour Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I created a webpage, and I have made my own light switch where it basically inverts colours, black goes to white and vice versa but I can't seem to get my links to change colour. I want my anchor tags as well as a:visited, a:link to all change to a different colour but can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><a title="Link to My Cover Letter & CV" href="index.html">My Cover Letter & CV</a> | </li>
        <li><a title="Link to My Projects" href="">My Projects</a> | </li>
        <li><a title="Link to Temp" href="">Temp</a> | </li>
        <li><a title="Link to Temp" href="personalDev.html">Temp</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav> <!-- Closes Nav -->
```

CSS:

```
/*Links*/
a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 1s;
}

/*Link hovering*/
nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);
function handleDocumentLoad() {

    //Variable
    var offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOff
    var onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOn
    var border = document.getElementById("mainContent"); //Targets the mainContent
    offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
    onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
    onSwitch.style.display = "none";

    //Event Listener
    offSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOff); //When clicked this action is performed
    onSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOn); //When clicked this action is performed

    //Function
    function lightsOff() { /*This changes the background colour to black and makes text white*/
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        document.body.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
        border.style.borderColor = "#FFFFFF";
        onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
        onSwitch.style.display = "inline";
        offSwitch.style.display = "none";
    }

    function lightsOn() { /*This changes the background colour to a white and makes text black*/
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.body.style.color = "#000000";
        border.style.borderColor = "#000000";
        offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
        onSwitch.style.display = "none";
        offSwitch.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Also I was wondering if there was a way to save the page state so for example the user presses the light switch, refreshes the page and it's still the same.

Comment: But you do not have elements with such id-s in your html. Am I missing something? And according to your comments you actually don't have any code working with anchor tags in js

Comment: It would be a way better idea to just set a class to the body or html element via JS and then change the colours via a stylesheet. For one it's using CSS for the styling instead of settin inline-styles via JS, it's more readable, and also you'll be able to set styles for the pseudo classes `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active`. Also, any dynamically added contents would automatically have the correct styles.

Comment: You might consider creating two css classes that define lights on and off and then add and remove theses classes to your elements. You can add a class to an element by document.getElementById("peace").className = "light-on".  As for retaining on a page refresh then you should look into storing values in local storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hey there @Ryan , I'm not exactly sure how to tackle your issue. However, you can write hexadecimal shorthand for your colors to save some bytes (i.e. #000 = #000000, #FFF = #FFFFFF).

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan I didn't include all of my HTML but was showing how the rest of my switch works

Comment: @Ryan wrap your js code inside document.onreadystatechange(); also where is the element on whoes click you are triggering event?

Comment: Please include all your code, including HTML and whatever else you have there.

Comment: What color do you want your links to be ?

Comment: @Taurus I want the links to be white, so the background is black and links are white

Answer (score 2):

You could just use basic DOM style object?

```
<a id="link" href="#">this is a link</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById("link").style.color = "green";
</script>
```

Or if you could use jQuery?

```
<a id="link" href="#">this is a link</a>
<script>
    $( "a" ).css( {"color":"green"} );
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't work, I need to change multiple link colours, it only changes the first link colour if I tag them all with an id

Comment: @Ryan you should use the jQuery one since it targets all of the links and should work just fine... also i found out that i couldn't use DOM call to get all of the links at once using *document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");*

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);

function handleDocumentLoad() {

//Variable
var offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOff
var onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOn
var border = document.getElementById("mainContent"); //Targets the mainContent
offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
onSwitch.style.display = "none";

//Event Listener
offSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOff); //When clicked this action is performed
onSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOn); //When clicked this action is performed


var links = document.getElementsByClassName("links");


//Function
function lightsOff() { /*This changes the background colour to black and makes text white*/
document.body.className += " body_lights_off";
border.style.borderColor = "#FFFFFF";
onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
onSwitch.style.display = "inline";
offSwitch.style.display = "none";
var i;
for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
links.item(i).className += " links_lights_off";
}
}

function lightsOn() { /*This changes the background colour to a white and makes text black*/
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(" body_lights_off", "");
border.style.borderColor = "#000000";
offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
onSwitch.style.display = "none";
offSwitch.style.display = "inline";
var i;
for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
links.item(i).className = links.item(i).className.replace(" links_lights_off", "");
}
}


}
```

```css
.body_lights_off {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
}

/*Links*/
a, a:link, a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 1s;
}

/*Link hovering*/
nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.links_lights_off:link, .links_lights_off:visited {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
    <ol>
        <li><a class="links" title="Link to My Cover Letter & CV" href="index.html">My Cover Letter & CV</a> | </li>
        <li><a class="links" title="Link to My Projects" href="">My Projects</a> | </li>
        <li><a class="links" title="Link to Temp" href="">Temp</a> | </li>
        <li><a class="links" title="Link to Temp" href="personalDev.html">Temp</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav> <!-- Closes Nav -->

<button id="lightSwitchOn"></button>
<button id="lightSwitchOff"></button>

<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

You add a `links` class to each of the links, you then use `document.getElementsByClassName` in JS to get all these `links`-classed elements. In each of the 2 functions (`lightsOff` and `lightsOn`), you iterate through the `links` elements, accessing them using the syntax `links.item([index])`, and then you achieve the link-color changing effects via a `links_lights_off` class, which in the CSS, specifies that all the links with that class should have a white color, you add this class to each of the links in the `lightsOff` function, and you remove it from each link in the `lightsOn` function. 

A class is used for `document.body`'s `background-color`/`color` effects as well, same functionality as the `links_lights_off` class, add class in the `lights_off` function and remove it in the `lights_on` function. 

There were tons of improvements I could make, but I felt like so much at once would confuse you, mayhaps I was wrong.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask. If this is not the effect you seek, inform me.